# Prevent WiX from deleting MS Office AddIns folder on uninstall

Tags: windows, wix, installation

Using WiX to build an installer. As part of the install process, I want to install an Excel Add-In to the generic Excel Add-Ins folder (`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\AddIns`). Here is the relevant portion of code that I've written:

```
<Directory Id="MicrosoftFolder" Name="Microsoft">
  <Directory Id="AddInsFolder" Name="AddIns">
    <Component Id="COMP_MyAddInLib" Guid="MY-GUID-HERE">
      <File Source="\MyAddInLib.xll" Id="LibMyAddIn" />
      <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Type="string" Key="Software\!(loc.ManufacturerName)\!(loc.ApplicationName)\MyAddIn" Name="INSTALLDIR" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" KeyPath="yes" />
      <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveAddInsFolder" On="uninstall" Property="AddInsFolder" />
      <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveMicrosoftFolder" On="uninstall" Property="MicrosoftFolder"/>
    </Component>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

This builds properly and it does work but, if my add-in is the only item in the user's `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\AddIns` folder, the AddIns folder gets deleted on uninstall. I'm not really sure if this could cause issues for Excel (or any other Office application) but obviously, since this folder is created by Office and not my install process, I'd like to avoid removing it.

I could remove the two `<RemoveFolder>` tags but then the build fails with two ICE64 errors.

Any thoughts on how I can remove my add-in file but preserve the folder structure and avoid the build failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't *always* own these folders and there could be other contents in them from another installation I would not use the RemoveFolder tags in your component.

This will give you some ICE validation warnings. If you know you shouldn't be removing these folders (You definitely don't own the %APPDATA%\Microsoft folder) then you know you should be leaving them behind. The component you are installing will get removed properly since you own that but it is right, in this case, to leave behind the folders.

What I would do is suppress ICE64 on release builds of your installer project but leave the ICE validation showing for debug.

Just define

```
<SuppressIces>ICE64</SuppressIces>
```

In the wixproj for the installer under your Release configuration.

Or add suppress ICE validation through the "WixProj properties > Tool Settings > Suppress specific ICE validations" if you are using Visual Studio.

If you are building explicitly with cmd line (calling light.exe on your wix files) you need to pass the switch -sice:ICE64

EDIT: Taking a look at the <RemoveFolder> tag it seems this will **not** remove folders that still have files or other folders in them so it should be OK to leave these two RemoveFolder tags in your component but I would still consider removing them and supressing the ICE64 validation warning.

Comment: Both answers are good but I like this since I think it's the safest solution. I'd prefer to leave folders that aren't created/owned by my install process untouched. I'm surprised that there's not a better built-in mechanism for this but supressing the ICE64 errors looks like the best way to go. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a custom action that just remakes the directory:

```
ExeCommand="cmd /C \"mkdir %APPDATA%\Microsoft\AddIns\""
```

I'd probably schedule it towards the end, maybe just before InstallFinalize, to make sure it runs after the folder gets deleted. Also make sure to ignore return code, or else it will fail if the folder still exists.

Comment: I experimented with this and it seems like a workable solution. I accepted the other answer simply because I think it's safer in that it doesn't alter the folder structure. Many thanks for the help.